# Factorize a number into coprime numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math

I want to know if there is a way to factorize a number into coprime numbers;

for example $N = a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot a_3 \cdots a_i$

And $a_i$ and $a_j$ are coprime for any $i \ne j$

Thanks

Comment: Yes, and it's even unique up to order, if you maximize the number of factors: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic

Comment: Obviously, prime numbers are all coprime. But you probably wanted something else.

Comment: Yes there are coprimes, for example 20 = 2 * 2 * 5, so a0 = 2 , a1 = 2, and 2 & 2 are not coprimes

Comment: Yes, it's easy. N = N is a coprime factorization.

Comment: Factorize into prime powers, then group these together arbitrarily

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I didn't understand your approach

Comment: Thanks @HagenvonEitzen, i got it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct this from the prime factorization. Just group all the appearances of the same prime factor to obtain $N=\prod p_i^{n_i}$. Since $p_i,p_j$ are distinct primes, any power of them has no non-unit common factors.